# can't use better_player as an audio player

Tags: flutter, video-player

I'm trying to use better_player as an audio player and I'm getting this error:
Video does work, the audio type is m4a.
As I understood video initialized is false, but it does get the duration of the file which means it can read it.

This is my output:

````
read media type: audio/mp4a-latm
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11504): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11504): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11504): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11504): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11504): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11504): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11504): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
I/CCodecConfig(11504): query failed after returning 20 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(11504): c2 config diff is Dict {
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 coded.aac-packaging.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 64000
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::i32 coding.drc.album-mode.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::float coding.drc.attenuation-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::float coding.drc.boost-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::i32 coding.drc.effect-type.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::float coding.drc.encoded-level.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::float coding.drc.reference-level.value = -16
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 input.delay.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   string input.media-type.value = "audio/mp4a-latm"
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 2
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::float output.drc.output-loudness.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   string output.media-type.value = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 raw.channel-mask.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 raw.max-channel-count.value = 8
D/CCodecConfig(11504):   c2::u32 raw.sample-rate.value = 44100
D/CCodecConfig(11504): }
I/MediaCodec(11504): MediaCodec will operate in async mode
D/MediaCodec(11504): flushMediametrics```


I'm using this fork:
https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer
````